# How can I scale a container to match its scaled (or otherwise transformed) content?

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a `<div>`, inside of which some complicated content is rendered with a scale transform applied. My problem is that the `<div>` takes up the same space that it would have taken even if no transform was applied. I've made a [jsFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/7HhpM/15/) to illustrate what I mean.

[I think I can understand why the behavior is like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg709742.aspx), but **is there any way to make it so that the container takes as much space as *its content with scaling (and other transforms, if possible) applied?***

I should note that explicitly setting the `width` and `height` of the `<div>` outside affects the contents of the scaled text (and this is not desired behavior in my case). Putting the scaled content in an `<iframe>` is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure what browser you're testing on, but for me (Chrome 27 / Firefox 22), I have to modify to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7HhpM/15/) to actually see the transform effect. Edit: looks like Chrome/Firefox doesn't accept transform on `display:inline`. Opera 12 works well though.

Comment: @Passerby Yeah, I'm working with Opera and forgot to test my snippet on other browsers. I made them `inline` just so that my point would be more recognizable visually, but that part is not critical to the question. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll include your snippet instead.

Comment: transform-origin:top left;   or else coordinates could be a beginning to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without resorting to Javascript, there isn't any way to do this, I don't think. CSS transforms don't affect layout flow for elements near the transformed elements, they only change the coordinate system within that element; so children are affected, but not parents or siblings ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) has some more detail on this).

There's a great answer here that might be a JS-based partial solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913299/2524360

Comment: It's definitely better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but it doesn't seem to accept 0 as a value. The browsers scales from 1, as in 100% to e.g. 4, or 400%.

```
transform:scale(1,4);
```