# How to scale a group of div sizes down using JQuery in a manner where they don't have spaces between them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a fiddle. I don't want spaces between the divs when they shrink.

http://jsfiddle.net/TnVEN/

```
$("#container").click(function(){




    $(".synth").css({
        'transition': 'all 1s',
        'transform': 'scale(0.5)',
         float:"right"             //Shouldn't this kill the spaces???


    });
})
```

Comment: Please try [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) to change position of transformed elements

Comment: Otherwise check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858523/css-transform-with-element-resizing?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like its what I'm going for.