# Scale image bug

Tags: html, css

My html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ef/1e/45/ef1e450945a5a7ff0c4b7776810d4f90.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/3b/85/0e3b858ffcfdbfa02b562c3dc7e3b5e1.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/df/c7/88/dfc7889e5dd99ad0c45834b4e4675389.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
```

My css:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.scale-img {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

In my page I have several imgs, and each of the img's size is different, I don't want to set size in css for each img, and I just want to scale each img to half of its original size. But the wrapper div stay the img its original size, I don't know where go wrong?

Comment: [My jsbin](http://jsbin.com/noqavi/7)

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858523/css-transform-with-element-resizing/10913299#10913299).

Comment: I have amended my answer to include something that may help fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... For better understanding, I have used a dummy image.

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
}
.scale-img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="scale-img" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
```

Comment: It not fit my situation

Comment: Do you want the the div to have fixed size? and the image to be of the half of the size?

Comment: No, In my page I have several imgs, and each of the img's size is different, I don't want to set size in css for each img, and I just want to scale each img to half of its original size and the wrapper div's size is equal to the img size(half of original size)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `transform` doesn't affect the parent is because it "[*modifies the coordinate space of the CSS visual formatting model*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)".

So in effect, it's sort of like doing this:

```css
#container {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}
#container span {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  right:50px;
  bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In an attempt to fix your issue, you'll more than likely need a bit of JavaScript:

```js
var objScaleIMGs = document.querySelectorAll('img.scale-img') // Grab all the images that need scaling.
for (var i = 0; i < objScaleIMGs.length; i++) { // Loop through all the images, setting their dimensions half of what they currently are.
  var h = objScaleIMGs[i].height;
  var w = objScaleIMGs[i].width;
  objScaleIMGs[i].height = h / 2;
  objScaleIMGs[i].width = w / 2;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
.scale-img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ef/1e/45/ef1e450945a5a7ff0c4b7776810d4f90.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/3b/85/0e3b858ffcfdbfa02b562c3dc7e3b5e1.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="scale-img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/df/c7/88/dfc7889e5dd99ad0c45834b4e4675389.jpg" alt="my img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transform the wrapper instead if you want to change the div's size with the change in img original size. The reason being that scale is used for img and not for wrapper div.

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 960px;
  width: 540px;
}
.scale-img {
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}
```

You should refer: [CSS Transform with element resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858523/css-transform-with-element-resizing/10913299#10913299)

> The problem I noticed is that when element scales, browser change its pixels ratio, not pixels amount. Element is smaller but it doesn't change its actual pixel size in DOM. Because of that I don't think that CSS-only solution exist.

Comment: @wupeng what is the issue now?

Comment: I did as you answer, and div is scaled, but the div's size was still the img original size

Comment: @wupeng can u edit the question to include what actually is happening and what u expect? like screenshots

Comment: @wupeng In that case you should set the height and width of the wrapper instead of transforming the img. See the edit.

Comment: In my page, I have several imgs and each of the img size is different, I dont want to set many size in css and scale my img to half of its original size just meet my needs, so I scaled my img in css and then I encounter my bug

Comment: @wupeng So you have many img, and how do u see those fit in wrapper? May you explain the expected thing instead of giving little hints.