# Toggle "display" property before/after CSS transition in a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I tried to create a dropdown menu, clicking on a toggle icon.

This is a [jsFiddle with a very simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/wnbvumr4/3/). The core of script is:

```
if( !$(target).hasClass('open') )
    $(target).show().addClass('open');
else
    $(target).removeClass('open').on('transitionend',function(e){
      $(target).hide();
  });
```

My problem is that submenu must appear with a `transform:scale()` from 0 to 1, BUT **I need that container** (highlighed by red borders) **adapt it's size depending by appereance of submenu**.

Hiding it runs correctly with my code, but showing it does not fire `scale` transition and I don't know how to solve...

Comment: try adding open class to the parent and animate the child. that will work for sure.

Comment: It seems there is no easy solution for. The best post for this thema I've found is this: [CSS Transform with element resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858523/css-transform-with-element-resizing)

Comment: @Era I thought about applying css class to parent, especially to optimize performances applying only one class and not two on different elementes (toggle and menu) but I don't understand how this could help for my specific problem

Comment: @AndyTschiersch Thanks Andy, I read that question/answer and I found a possible solution but... it relies on pre-calculating final width/height of container. I thought about a similar solution too but.... is not so efficient....  like "fire to a bug with a bazooka" :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` when toggling with CSS using animation. This also concerns usage of jQuery `show / hide`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution because with `visibility: hidden` container remain always "big", as evident by red borders, while I need that it become large only as much as toggle button when dropdown is collapsed

Comment: Is animating width/height instead an option?

Comment: No for the same reasons, performances. Please look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Paint_Flashing_Tool) to more details about why transforms are better.