# decrease width of a div by a random number on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

its my code and I wanna decrease width of div any time click on button with random number

```
let humanDiv = document.getElementById("humanDiv");
let monsterDiv = document.getElementById("monsterDiv");

function attBtn() {
let numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
humanDiv.style.width -= numRandom + 'px';
monsterDiv.style.width -= numRandom + 'px';
}
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: Why are you using Javascript and not CSS?  Make your code a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.style.width` gives you a string you can't use `-=` on it.

Try :

```js
humanDiv.style.width = parseInt(humanDiv.style.width)+ numRandom + 'px';
monsterDiv.style.width = parseInt(monsterDiv.style.width) + numRandom + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of an element can't be accessed when it wasn't set previously:

```js
 console.log(humanDiv.style.width);

// will give 
//
// (nothing)
```

So it doesn't make sense to subtract nothing by a random number.

CSS transform might help you:
[CSS Transform with element resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858523/css-transform-with-element-resizing).

Answer (score 0):

humanDiv.style.width properties returns string with the pixels in the end so before decreasing it you should convert this property into the number.

```
<script>
  let humanDiv = document.getElementById("humanDiv");
  let monsterDiv = document.getElementById("monsterDiv");

  function attBtn() {
    let numRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
    let humanDivWidth = new Number(humanDiv.style.width.slice(0, -2));
    let monsterDivWidth = new Number(humanDiv.style.width.slice(0, -2));
    humanDiv.style.width = humanDivWidth - numRandom + "px";
    monsterDiv.style.width = monsterDivWidth - numRandom + "px";
  }
</script>
```